# Not able to generate Access token using Slack API

Tags: javascript, node.js, access-token, slack-api

I am trying to get access token from Slack API,

With the below-given code, I get an authorisation URL which has a temporary code in the URL query.
After granting the permissions, it is redirected to `/slack/oauthcallback`

```
const slackAuthorizeUrl = `https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=${slackClientId}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(slackRedirectUri)}&scope=users:read,chat:write,channels:read`

app.get('/slack/auth', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ authUrl: slackAuthorizeUrl })
})
```

Using the below-given code I exchange the code with accesstoken.
But unfortunately, I am not able to do that. I get an error saying, invalid code.

```
app.get('/slack/oauth2callback', (req, res) => {
    const { code } = req.query
    console.log('callback code- ', code)


    const tokenExchangeUrl = 'https://slack.com/api/oauth.v2.access';
    const tokenExchangeData = {
        client_id: slackClientId,
        client_secret: slackClientSecret,
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: slackRedirectUri,
    };

    axios.post(tokenExchangeUrl, tokenExchangeData).then(res => {
        const userToken = res.data

        console.log('user data - ', userToken)
    })

    res.status(200).send('recieved code')
})
```

Here's the userToken (response from token exchange axios post)

```
 user data -  {
  ok: false,
  error: 'invalid_code',
  warning: 'missing_charset',
  response_metadata: { warnings: [ 'missing_charset' ] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the `tokenExchangeData` as JSON, but the `oauth.v2.access` endpoint accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You need to send the data as form params.

You can do this easily in Axios like

```
axios.post(url, new URLSearchParams({
  client_id: 'your_client_id',
  client_secret: 'your_client_secret',
  code: 'your_temporary_code',
  redirect_uri: 'your_redirect_uri'
}))
```